# What is the max size of a UITabBarItem image?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

What is the max size of a UITabBarItem image?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From apple's UITabBarItem reference:

> The item’s image. If nil, an image is
>   not displayed. The images displayed on
>   the tab bar are derived from this
>   image. If this image is too large to
>   fit on the tab bar, it is scaled to
>   fit. The size of an tab bar image is
>   typically 30 x 30 points. The alpha
>   values in the source image are used to
>   create the unselected and selected
>   images—opaque values are ignored.

I hope it helps! good luck!

Comment: to compliment, see doc [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW8)

Answer (score 6):

It is not scaled but ***clipped***. So remember to scale the image before using it.

> The item’s image. If nil, an image is not displayed. The images
>   displayed on the tab bar are derived from this image. If this image is
>   too large to fit on the tab bar, it is ***clipped*** to fit. The size
>   of a tab bar image is typically 30 x 30 points. The alpha values in
>   the source image are used to create the unselected and selected
>   images—opaque values are ignored.